# getting deployment exception in JBOSS 5.1.1

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, jboss5.x

We are updating the version of the JBoss from 4.x to 5.1.1.

I am placing the EAR in jboss 5.1.1 and as soon as I start my application I am getting the

```
"The content of element type "message-driven" must match "(ejb-name,destination-jndi-name,mdb-
user?,mdb-passwd?,mdb-client-id?,mdb-subscription-id?,configuration-name?,security-proxy?,ejb-
ref*,resource-ref*,resource-env-ref*,depends*)"."
```

the above exception, I tried changing the DTD in ejb-jar.xml but it is throwiing same exception

This ear was previously successfully deployed in JBoss 4 .

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do would be to load up your **ejb-jar.xml** file in a good XML editor to make sure it is not malformed.  You said you changed the DTD, but have you tried validating it against the DTD and, if so, what validation errors do you get?

I've seen errors similar to yours as the result of having stupid typos and/or words without the correct casing in my XML configuration files.